# Is it possible to drill down in the DHIS2 visualizer?

Tags: dhis2, data

In DHIS2, I'm trying to create a chart (column chart or pie chart) with drill down on organization unit, period, or data dimension.

I have not been able to do that.  How do I do so?

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not supported. There is an issue for this feature in the DHIS 2 issue tracker. You can up-vote it from here:

https://jira.dhis2.org/browse/DHIS2-7031